# why don´t run php upload file on this code

Tags: php

I want to control the size of the photos I upload to the server, but I have something wrong in the code and I can not see it. Can anyone help me?

if the photo is smaller than 2MB work fine, but when is larger than 2mb does not work the error path. I get errors in the "if" for files smaller than 2mb.

this is the code:

```
<?php session_start(); 
include("includes/conexiones.php");
$sql="SELECT * FROM trabajos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1" ;
$resultado=mysql_query($sql);
$fila=mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
$lastid=$fila["id"];
$prefijo=$lastid+1;
if ($_POST["cserv"]!=""){
$servicio=$_POST["cserv"];}
if ($_POST["cdirv"]!=""){
$direccion=$_POST["cdirv"];}
if ($_POST["cobserv"]!=""){
$observaciones=$_POST["cobserv"];}
if ($_FILES["cfoto"]!=""){
$foto=$_FILES["cfoto"]["name"];
$nombrefoto=$prefijo.$foto;
$Upload=$_FILES["cfoto"]["name"];
$Type=$_FILES["cfoto"]["type"];
$Size=$_FILES["cfoto"]["size"];
}
if($Size > 2097152){
header("location:error.php");
}
if($Size < 2097152){
$fototmp=$_FILES["cfoto"]["tmp_name"];
list($ancho, $alto)=getimagesize($fototmp);
$nuevoancho=600;
$nuevoalto=600*$alto/$ancho;
$nuevaimg=imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoancho, $nuevoalto);
$idnuevaimg=imagecreatefromjpeg($fototmp);
imagecopyresized($nuevaimg,$idnuevaimg,0,0,0,0,$nuevoancho,$nuevoalto,$ancho,$alto);
imagejpeg ($nuevaimg,"imagenes/grandes/".$nombrefoto);
$fototmp=$_FILES["cfoto"]["tmp_name"]; 
list($ancho, $alto)=getimagesize($fototmp);
$nuevoancho=144;
$nuevoalto=144*$alto/$ancho;
$nuevaimg=imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoancho, $nuevoalto);
$idnuevaimg=imagecreatefromjpeg($fototmp);
imagecopyresized($nuevaimg,$idnuevaimg,0,0,0,0,$nuevoancho,$nuevoalto,$ancho,$alto);
imagejpeg ($nuevaimg,"imagenes/peques/".$nombrefoto);
$sql="INSERT INTO trabajos (servicio, direccion, observaciones, foto) VALUES ('$servicio',         '$direccion', '$observaciones', '$nombrefoto')";
mysql_query($sql);
$idtrabajo=mysql_insert_id();
header("location:insertartrabajo2.php?vid=$idtrabajo"); 
}
?>
```

I want to protect the product when the client upload an image larger than 2MB, no mysql errors appear on the screen, although to tell the client that you can not upload files larger than 2MB, someday he will. if anyone has a better solution, I'm open to advice.

thanks

Comment: Increase `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `php.ini`

Comment: I have placed this: php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
php_value post_max_size 30M

Comment: Of course no mysql-errors appears, because you never output errors. Use `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: I will not hide the mistakes, I handle errors. If there is a file is larger than 2 mb, shows this error and the file weighs less than 2mb running this. "error.php" is a page created by my